# In how many ways can $3$ rewards be distributed if two race entrants are known to have won an award and two others are known not to have won an award?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

50 in race, including A,B, C,D.

At the end of the race, C and D lost are known to have lost. A and B are known to have won a reward.

If there are 3 rewards to be given out, how many ways are there to distribute the rewards.

I think the answer ought to be

46C1 (Choose the last person) * 3C2 ( choose the first reward to be given) * 2C1 ( choose second reward to be given.

A TA said this answer should be multiplied by 6.  I think this is wrong however. As this will lead to over counting.  (A,B,C) being given (R1,R2,R3)  is the same as  (B,A,C) being given (R2,R1,R3).

A simpler example of this is if were choosing team members. choosing Sara then Steve is the same as choosing Steve as sally.

Am I miscounting something as overcounting?

Comment: Are the rewards different (e.g. Gold, Silver, Bronze)?

Comment: "*Should be multiplied by 6*" They might not have seen your `3C2 * 2C1` there which is the 6 they were probably talking about.

Comment: they have written so i reckon not.  
(46C1 *3C2*2C1)*6

Comment: the rewards are different Karl

Comment: $\binom{46}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{1}$ seems correct here.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct and your justification is good.

One way to help see it extra clearly would be to consider a smaller problem. What if there are only 5 people total? In that case there are only 6 possible final placements and you can write them all out on the board in a few seconds: ABE, AEB, BEA, BAE, EAB, EBA.

I would suggest discussing this smaller version with your TA. If there's some misunderstanding about how the problem should be interpreted, then the smaller problem will probably reveal it quickly. If the TA just made a mistake then the smaller problem will probably help them understand that too, since they presumably can't come up with 36 different reward distributions in this smaller case. (I would advise this approach of using smaller examples to sanity checking your formulas in general. You won't always have a disagreeing TA, but you can still sanity check your own formulas by plugging in small values so that you can confirm the answer by hand.)